# How to find out whether Auto Layout was used to make a Storyboard or Xib

Tags: ios, autolayout

In iOS, is there a way to programmatically find out whether a storyboard, or xib, has been defined using Auto Layout or Springs & Struts?

This would be useful when writing a method which needs to be able to operate on either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the contained views for the `view.constraints` property.

Specifically:

```
if (someView.constraints.count) { 
    // Autolayout
} else {
    // Sprints & struts
}
```

Comment: Specifically, you could use `if (view.constraints.count) { … }`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe by checking `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` Boolean

Comment: NOTE: If you add views in Interface Builder, the system automatically sets this property to NO.